# ActiveRecord: Best way to add a 'fake' model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton, rails-activerecord

In our Rails application, the `Post` resource can be made by either a `User` or an `Admin`.

Thus, we have an ActiveRecord model class called `Post`, with a `belongs_to :author, polymorphic: true`.

However, in certain conditions, the system *itself* is supposed to be able to create posts.
Therefore, I'm looking for a way to add e.g. `System` as `author`.

Obviously, there will only ever be one `System`, so it is not stored in the database.

Naïvely attempting to just add an instance (e.g. the singleton instance) of `class System; end` as author returns errors like `` NoMethodError: undefined method `primary_key' for System:Class ``.

What would be the cleanest way to solve this?

Is there a way to write a 'fake' ActiveRecord model that is not actually part of the database?

Comment: It's not a matter of Active Record, it's all about the database. You have to provide some foreign key for `posts` table. So, one of the solutions is to create (via seeds) first Admin with name "System" and use it as "System" author.

Comment: You could add a boolean attribute called `created_by_system` to your `Post` model. Then you have to add `optional: true` to your `belongs_to :author` association so it's possible to leave the association empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up with creating the following 'fake' model class that does not require any changes to the database schema.

It which leverages a bit of meta-programming:

```rb
# For the cases in which the System itself needs to be given an identity.
# (such as when it does an action normally performed by a User or Admin, etc.)
class System
  include ActiveModel::Model
  class << self
    # The most beautiful kind of meta-singleton
    def class
      self
    end

    def instance
      self
    end

    # Calling`System.new` is a programmer mistake; 
    # they should use plain `System` instead.
    private :new

    def primary_key
      :id
    end

    def id
      1
    end

    def readonly?
      true
    end

    def persisted?
      true
    end

    def _read_attribute(attr)
      return self.id if attr == :id

      nil
    end

    def polymorphic_name
      self.name
    end

    def destroyed?
      false
    end

    def new_record?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Of main note here is that `System` is both its own class and its own instance.
This has the following advantages:

- We can just pass `Post.new(creator: System)` rather than `System.new` or `System.instance`
- There is at any point only one system.
- We can define the class methods that ActiveRecord requires (`polymorphic_name`) on `System` itself rather than on `Class`.

Of course, whether you like this kind of metaprogramming or find it too convoluted is very subjective.

What is less subjective is that overriding ActiveRecord's `_read_attribute` is not nice; we are depending on an implementation detail of ActiveRecord. Unfortunately to my knowledge there is no public API exposed that could be used to do this more cleanly. (In our project, we have some specs in place to notify us immediately when ActiveRecord might change this.)

Comment: Did this actually work for you? I am getting an error on `current_scope` missing. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this actually worked. Maybe there is a change in Rails 7 that breaks it?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways that I see that make the most sense:

### Option A: Add a 'system' `Author` record to the DB

This isn't a horrible idea, it just shifts the burden onto you making sure certain records are present in every environment. But you can always create these records in seed files if you want to ensure they're always created.

The benefit over option B is that you can just use standard `ActiveRecord` queries to find all of the system's `Post`s.

### Option B: Leave the association nil and add a new flag for `:created_by_system`

This is what I would opt for. If a `Post` was made by the system, just leave the author reference blank and set a special flag to indicate this model was created internally.

You can still have a method to quickly get a list of all of them just by making a scope:

```
  scope :from_system, -> { where(created_by_system: :true) }
```

---

Which one you choose I think depends on whether you want to be able to query `Post.author` and get information about the System. In that case you need to take option A. Otherwise, I would use option B. I'm sure there's some other ways to do it too but I think this makes the most sense.

Comment: When copied Fabian's comment, you forgot `optional: true`. And `null: true` migration for `author_id` column of course. And I even don't talk about nullable reference idea itself.

Comment: He never said if the reference was set to optional already or not, so I'm going off the assumption it's already optional. But yeah, I mean it's implied that you're going to need a migration here.

Comment: Also I am willing to bet 99% of Rails programmers would come up with one of these two solutions to this problem, so no I did not copy your comment.